# want to split incoming web traffic to a specific url to android and iphone

Tags: android, ios, redirect

I have 2 seperate free app versions that I want to promote via one link and have the IOS user sent to an IOS page and the android user sent to the android page. Have googled it and found htaccess answers and answers to send just ios traffic or ipad traffic but not how to split iphone /android on the one page.

Thanks in advance as I am very basic at java etc and still trying to learn.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a simple php script that checks for the browser's user agent and then depending on that redirects to either the android or the iOS page.

Comment: Thanks, in the end I have used this though not sure if this will be fully effective across all androids and iphone models.
_
<script type="text/javascript">

if(/Android/.test(navigator.userAgent)){

if(document.URL !="http://yahoo.com")

  {

    window.location ="http://yahoo.com";

  }

}

</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

if(/iPhone/.test(navigator.userAgent)){

if(document.URL !="http://google.com")

  {

    window.location ="http://google.com";

  }

}

</script>

Comment: appreciate any feedback if someone see why this would not work across all android and iphones